# To what extent does D&D 5e imply a setting?

Tags: discussion, dnd-5e

[This D&D 5e question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/201107/16003) appears to be a question about in-universe lore (and was tagged [lore](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore)), but doesn't specify any specific setting. Does D&D 5e imply a specific setting?  Should we assume Forgotten Realms?

More generally, to what extent should we consider 5e questions as existing with particular setting assumptions?   For example, this one of the answers to this question uses the "gods get their power from the belief of their worshipers" idea.  I suspect that that model for divine power, though commonly used, is not spelled out in the rule books, and so it is not necessarily the case that all campaign settings need to follow that model.

This is a little bit different from [this question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8225/16003) in that what I'd like to discuss is what, if any, assumptions we can make about the setting for generic 5e question, rather than asking if a setting is required to specified for questions with the lore tag.

Comment: Just a quick PSA: let's make sure not to focus on the tag. With the exception of system tags, tags are purely for describing and categorising based on the content of the question and don't/shouldn't imply new additional things about the question. The lore tag being present or absent shouldn't change the nature of how we handle the content. So instead, let's look at what we should focus on, which is the content of the question—it seems to be about in-game lore, do we need more information than "it's D&D 5e"?

Comment: @doppelgreener sure, but I figure NautArch added it for a reason.  Plus, I found that when I tried to answer it, much of my answer was "well it depends on the setting" and thus the DM.  And as mentioned in the question, one of the thorough answers did pull in, what I consider to be, setting assumptions.

Comment: Related from main: [Is Forgotten Realms the default setting in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45584/52137)

Answer (score 9):

#### D&D 5e does not imply a particular setting. If the setting is unclear, and you think it matters, ask them to clarify.

[D&D has numerous official campaign settings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/34/62294). If I tell you "I'm playing D&D 5e", I've told you the game I'm playing, not the setting I am playing that game in. D&D 5e also has core rules and player options that work *independent* of your choice of campaign setting. So a question tagged [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) does not *a priori* imply a particular setting, even though it does imply some things about the setting, by virtue of the rules working across settings (e.g. spellcasting, certain monsters, connection to certain planes). Lore questions *may* imply at least some sense of being part of the "D&D Multiverse", which [KRyan's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12198/62294) explains nicely, again by making certain assumptions based on the rules.

However, some questions are setting *dependent*, not because of the game system the querent is playing, but because of the particular content they are enquiring about. If you think the setting matters for a question but it hasn't been specified, just ask them. If they have no specific setting in mind, and your *really* think their question has numerous, vastly different answers in different settings, to the point that the question should be split into multiple distinct questions, you can vote to close for "needs more focus", though we have seen questions do just fine without being split up, even when the answer was setting dependent.

#### For this specific question, there are no exceptional settings respecting paladins.

Sometimes it does take a bit of system knowledge and expertise to know when a question is appropriately scoped, and in this case, I think the question is just fine. Sure, there may be some minor differences setting to setting in the particular details of how paladin oaths manifest, but since there are no official 5e settings with major exceptions for paladins, any minor details are better documented by an ambitious answer, rather than by multiple questions.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would prefer to see the final paragraph emphasize that in many cases, a question might have _a very few, small exceptions_ in particular settings, and it’s entirely reasonable to ask people to answer with “well it’s usually foo, but in XYZ it’s bar, and in ABC it’s actually baz.” We should only vote to close for needing more focus when the question _needs_ more focus, that is, it really just is impossible to answer in a reasonable manner with all the different exceptions. Splitting up a question unnecessarily does more harm than good.

Comment: @KRyan Yeah, I'll add some detail there, and I'm adding a paragraph about how this particular question is just fine as written.

Comment: Nice. Also, I’d comment that “D&D 5e” alone definitely _implies_ some things about the setting, e.g. the existence of magic, the functioning of a lot of that magic as spells, the existence of monsters and need for adventurers, etc. etc. “D&D 5e is a game system, not a setting” really does not sit right with me.

Answer (score 7):

#### The Multiverse covers everything

D&D has a conceit that all campaign settings are embedded within an “oversetting,” known (currently) simply as “the Multiverse.” There are a large number of things that more-or-less “multiversal,” that is, they behave the same way everywhere in the multiverse—within each campaign setting as well as outside any of them, on the other planes.

Thus, it makes perfect sense to ask a question about lore within D&D that isn’t specific to any one setting, because there are things generally shared by all settings. This is, in fact, Wizards of the Coast’s preference for nearly *everything*—they like to keep D&D pretty consistent across campaign settings when they can, because it makes it easier for players to get into new settings (read: become convinced to buy new products). Thus, most stuff—magic, spells, classes, feats, etc. etc.—all have the same lore behind them no matter where you go.

As for the “default” of the Forgotten Realms, Wizards of the Coast has been adamant that this is not the case for 5e. They **have** exported a number of things (e.g. the Weave) that were previously specific to FR, making them general concepts throughout the Multiverse, but officially, that isn’t because FR is the default, it’s because they’re ret-conning every place else to be a little more like FR. (And FR has had some of this coming back at it, particularly the necessity of patron deities.)

#### The Multiverse is also its own setting

The Multiverse is *also* setting in its own right, with its own canon, history, characters, and so on. It is entirely reasonable to ask questions about it. Though it contains the Forgotten Realms, and Greyhawk and Eberron and Krynn and so on, plenty of things go on outside of those, and often go unnoticed within those—vagaries of the Blood War across the Lower Planes rarely influence life on the ground in Toril, for example.

It might be reasonable for there to be a [dnd-multiverse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-multiverse) for questions about these things, but I don’t see a lot of need for it, personally. I wouldn’t apply that to questions about, say, how spellcasting works within D&D’s lore—even though that is “multiversal,” it isn’t specific to the Multiverse as a setting, it applies to pretty much all D&D.

Comment: Are there resources that explain what things are multiversal?

Comment: @Dave Yes... ish. In 5e, what information exists is scattered around several books, mostly in various individual monster descriptions and the like, and mostly with very little detail. It mostly—but not perfectly—hints at the greater detail found in prior editions of D&D, especially 2e and 3e, where the non-Material planes formed an entire product line known as Planescape. But it can be very difficult to know what has or hasn’t been ret-conned since then, particularly since it’s hard to know how to interpret WotC not mentioning things in 5e—and 5e is relatively _very_ sparse on lore.

Comment: @Dave But that kind of thing is literally _why this site exists and has value_: you can find here experts who are familiar enough with those books to synthesize that material.